# Look up speed of a std::hash_map vs std::vector

Tags: c++

In the following code would it be as fast to use a `std::hash_map`. I assume that the `std::hash_map` adds the extra step of needing a hash function to the process of looking up, but could the hash function be as fast a vector lookup?

```
bool isUniqueChars(const string &str){
        if (str.length() > 128){
            return false;
        }
        vector<bool> char_set(128);
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            int val = str[i];
            if (char_set[val]){
                return false;
            }
            char_set[val] = true;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: I like to think of arrays and vectors as highly optimized versions of a hash map.

Comment: Vector lookup by index is already O(1) without hashing, you can't get faster.

Comment: If speed is your ultimate goal, you might find `vector<char>` to be faster than `vector<bool>` because the specialization for bool requires extra code for bit manipulation.

Comment: There is no `std::hash_map` in C++. Did you mean `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: @DanM. `hash_map` was a popular compiler extension before `unordered_map` was put into the standard.  Don't know if any compiler ever included it in `std::` though.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'd just go with `bool char_set[256]`.

Comment: Just test it yourself. You can swap the vector with unordered_map etc and time it. What is the problem?

Comment: If anything, you would likely be better off with `std::unordered_set` than `std::unordered_map`. You are just mapping values to a `bool` to know if that value is part of the set. It carries no additional information, as you can't have an element with the value `false` in your map. If a value would map to `false`, it would simply not be in the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all performance-related questions, you should measure the difference to answer your own question. Fortunately, with this simple code it is easy enough.

Hash data structures have *amortized* constant complexity, i.e. the average time per operation is constant only if you do many operations. So I expect `unordered_set` to be slightly slower than `vector`.

Note that you can also use [`std::bitset<128>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) - it has little overhead, like `vector`, and may be more descriptive - its size is constant, while `vector` can be resized.

Comment: Even if you do a lot of operations, I can't see how any kind of hashtable will be faster than an indexed lookup. Hashtables make sense when the key domain is not contiguous integers -- the bucket structure effectively converts the key domain to a set of contiguous integers with the help of a suitable hash function. In this case the domain _is_ contiguous integers, so all the hashtable does is add hash overhead to what was already a simple lookup-by-index.

Comment: Some implementations insist on bound-checking all accesses to `vector`s. Also, specifically `vector<bool>` contains bit-level logic, which can be slow (but probably is OK). But I agree, `vector` should be faster than hash-related containers.

Comment: Agreed on those points. Though bounds checking surely is cheaper than `std::hash`. :)

Comment: @cdhowie the standard for `vector` has two lookup functions, `operator[]` and `.at()`.  When not compiled for debug, `operator[]` shouldn't do any bounds checking, that's what `at` is for.

Comment: @MarkRansom Right, I knew that -- I'm just saying that even with bounds checking, vector would (most likely) be faster than a hashtable.